# Java 8 Stream illegal exception

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

============== UPDATED ==============: 
Actually i am getting stream as an argument to my method and i cant change that. And i have to process it thrice.

```
MyAggregate aggregate(Stream<IncomingProduct> products){
        Supplier<Stream<IncomingProduct>> streamSupplier
                = () -> products;
        if(streamSupplier.get() == null || !streamSupplier.get().findAny().isPresent()){
            return null;
        }
        List<MyProduct> myProducts = streamSupplier.get()
                .map(p -> new MyProduct(p.getName(), p.getPrice()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        BigDecimal price = myProducts.stream()
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
        return new MyAggregate(myProducts,price);
    }
}
```

I am getting below exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed

Comment: Post the stacktrace or at least error message.

Comment: You can't consume a stream twice.

Comment: i have updated my question. Please bear the object name changes.

Comment: You can not reuse a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

Comment: Whatever “the object name” is supposed to be, it makes no difference. It’s still the same error, the supplier `() -> products` always returns the same `Stream` object.

Comment: @Holger what should be done instead of this ? `Supplier<Stream<IncomingProduct>> streamSupplier
                = () -> products;`

Comment: Nothing. Just remove this declaration, together with the subsequent `if` statement. Just use `List<MyProduct> myProducts = products .map(p -> new MyProduct(p.getName(), p.getPrice())) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: i have to do certain processing if stream is null or stream is empty that is why there is if check. `if(products == null || !products.findAny().isPresent()){
            return null;
        }
        List<MyProduct> myProducts = products
                .map(p -> new MyProduct(p.getName(), p.getPrice()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`   This still fails when i do products.map

Comment: There is no “certain processing” in your code. There is just a questionable `null` handling (return `null` when the argument is `null`) and an even worse behavior (return `null` when the stream is empty) without any need. Just performing the collect operation will give you an empty result list for an empty stream, which is reasonable. If you still need to do a special operation in that case, it’s still possible at that point. If you insist on the questionable `null` handling, `if(products == null) return null;` will work.

Comment: @Holger Just FYI i am  returning null intentionally but i have to check for empty stream also and do some processing in this if block. Also if use products.findAny().isPresent() in my if block then i cant use products stream later.

Comment: As said, `if(products == null) return null;` will work, even when the coding style is not recommended. Also, as said, when you perform `List<MyProduct> myProducts = products .map(p -> new MyProduct(p.getName(), p.getPrice())) .collect(Collectors.toList());`, with an empty stream, there will be no problem, it will just evaluate to an empty list, so whatever you want to do in case of en empty stream can be done after that, as simple as `if(myProducts.isEmpty()) { /* your special action */ }`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't consume a stream twice. Your supplier needs to recreate it:

```
    Supplier<Stream<SoldProduct>> streamSupplier
            = () -> Stream.of(s1,s2,s3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use stream twice like that once the stream has been accessed with any operation like map, filter or any other terminal operation like collect, anymatch, etc,. then you cannot use it again you have to store products in list and then use list.stream() so that you create new stream for both the operation

```
 List<SoldProduct> products = List.of(s1,s2,s3);
 Supplier<List<SoldProduct>> listSupplier
                = () -> products;
 listSupplier.get().stream().anyMatch(s -> true);
 listSupplier.get().stream().anyMatch(s -> true);
```

Comment: Or, keep it as a `Supplier<SoldProduct>`, and use `() -> products.stream()`.